# Sencha Extjs - How to use grid getRowClass() dynamically from Controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a checkbox column in my grid that displays Yes/No based on checkbox selection.

**Requirement:** 
If checkbox value == Yes, change row color Green
Else Leave as is (default).

**Steps I have taken so far:** 
On Ext.grid.View set the getRowClass function, something like this:

```
 viewConfig: {
 getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
 if (record.get('isApproved') == true)
   {
     return 'highlight-rowgreen';
   }                           
 },
```

This works perfectly fine. **However I want achieve this in a store.sync callback** which is not happening at the moment. There is no error, nothing. Just doesnt work.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('MyApp.MyStore');
        store.proxy.url = MYAPP.globals.url + "myapplication/" + branchNo + "/event/" + branchEventId;
        store.sync({
            scope: this,
            callback:function (records, operation, success) {
                if(records.proxy.reader.rawData.success){
                // Success. Set the rows color to green if not already done.                    
                   alert('Update Completed');
                   eventsGrid.getView().getRowClass = function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
                       console.log('I am here');
                       if (record.get('isApproved') == true)
                       {
                        return 'highlight-rowgreen';
                       }
                      };
                  }
                  else{
                     alert('Update failed');                   
                  }
                }
        });
```

What I cant see is my console log **"I am here"**. I can see the Alert message alright.

I have tried other solutions as well like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072153/how-to-dynamically-change-the-getrowclass-function-on-an-extjs-gridpanel-viewcon) but not happening.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Grid rows are re-rendered *whenever* the relevant record's data changes, and `getRowClass` will be called every time. It does not matter how the data gets changed — locally only or with the involvement of remote sync. Therefore there is no need to re-define `getRowClass` anywhere like you are doing in sync callback. Data change will result in re-rendering the row and placing or removing your `highlight-rowgreen` class accordingly. See [this example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pn4).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set rowclass again in store sync callback. It should work just as is. It could be that your grid view needs a refresh. Try this..

```
 store.sync({
        scope: this,
        callback:function (records, operation, success) {
            if(records.proxy.reader.rawData.success){
            // Success. Set the rows color to green if not already done.                    
               alert('Update Completed');
               eventsGrid.getView().refresh(); //refresh grid view
              }
              else{
                 alert('Update failed');                   
              }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But eventsGrid.getView().refresh(); doesnt do anything. The value of the record is correct, its only on the screen that it is not refreshed.

Comment: Hmm... as @DrakeES said, there is nothing to be done as such, it should work just as is. The getView().refresh() simply refreshes the grid view with your new data. Another thing to check is if the store instance in your grid is same as the one you are calling sync on. Sorry for the answer, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment so my hand was forced.